# Reading .xlsx files using OLEDB + Issues with certain cells not loading data

Tags: c#, excel, oledb

Hope someone can assist me here...

I am attempting to load a .xlsx file into a DataTable then process the information using C#.Net..

Got the basics up and running, connect using OLEDB, the data loads and I output it to a DataGridView to check the data.

The issue I am having is that some of the cells (only a few) do not load the data that is contained in the excel file. In my example Cell "C3" for example which is a General formatted cell like all the other cells on this row in excel does not load its contents.

The actual Cell should load as MEMBERSHIP but when outputting it to a gridview it shows a blank or when debugging the DataRow / Col value it is blank, even though the excel file has the data there for this cell. If I change the contents of this cell MEMBERSHIP to a number like 123456, then it loads this value ok, but If I change the value back to character it returns blank again.

A majority of the cells (13 of 15) load on this row except for 2, and they are of the same format.

Here is the connection string I am using in my code, actually got it from this site :):

```
try
{

string tabsheet = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(FullFileName); 
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FullFileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO'";

var adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + tabsheet + "$]",connectionString);

adapter.Fill(aDataTable); 
}
catch (Exception er)
{
logfile.AddToFile("GetDataTableFromCsv exception: " + er.Message);
}
```

Stuck, Help! :)

Answer (score 5):

My guess is that there are several cells in the same column above the one(s) with the string value 'MEMBERSHIP' that are numbers.  This causes OLEDB to infer that the data in these columns are numeric so non-numeric values will be ignored.

The solution is to include IMEX=1 in the Extended Properties section of your conn string:

```
string connectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + FullFileName + ";" + "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;'";
```

The Excel entry at [connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel) explains this property setting and also has a warning:

> "IMEX=1;" tells the driver to always read "intermixed" (numbers,
>   dates, strings etc) data columns as text. Note that this option might
>   affect excel sheet write access negative.

Comment: +1 I had this problem when developing software to do exactly this last year, and this resolved the same problem at the time.

Comment: Thanks that was the fix for my issue,.. now the cell with text displays fine... Cheers. :)